# Pandas value.count() error

Tags: python

My text file

```
Name     Surname    Age    Sex      Grade    X
Chris      M.        14     M       4     10 05 2010
Adam       A.        17     M             11 12 2011
Jack       O.               M       8     08 04 2009
...
```

I want to count years. 
Example output:
{ '2010' : 1 , "2011" : 1 ...} 
but I got "Key Error : Year".

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf("file.txt")

df.join(df['X'].str.split(' ', 2, expand = True).rename(columns={0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3}))

df.columns=["1"]
df["1"].value_counts().dict()
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `df` will remain original one, you have to assign to it after you join with new column, then you will get the `df` with column `Year`. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf("file.txt")
df = df.join(df['Date'].str.split(' ', 2, expand = True).rename(columns={1: 'Year', 0: 'Month'}))
df["Year"].value_counts().to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'2009': 1, '2010': 1, '2011': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found my error. stack = df.join... and then: stack["Year"].value_counts().to_dict()